Description Field in compact layout shows only limited lines

Hi,
I have created compact layout to show product Description, the product description only shows the first line and after that it gets truncated,
Can anyone please tell if there is a way to show more line here or will I have to make it custom.
Also is it standard salesforce functionality that we can only show this much content?
any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Due to the limited space available in these areas, only a few lines of text are shown to ensure that the layout remains clean and readable. Fields like the description field are truncated to fit within the compact layout's constraints. Compact layouts also control how records are displayed in the Salesforce mobile app. If your company uses the Salesforce mobile app, you can help your users see what they need on mobile screens, where space is limited and quick recognition of records is important.

To add to Tushdar's comment, you won't be able to customise this behaviour either. This popup isn't something that we can override.

Thankyou so much Tushar and Callum , much appreciated guys!
